# Join the single dictionary with the table format

Tags: python, dictionary, join, format

I am looking to join the key value with the table format

```
n = {'abcd':'alpha','efg':'beta'}
```

My current code

```
string = ("\n".join("{}==>{}".format(k,v) for k, v in n.item()))
```

CurrentOutput:

```
abcd ==> alpha
efg ==> beta
```

But would like to have something like this

```
Key     Value
abcd    alpha
efg     beta
```

I also tried setting width like

```
string = ("\n".join("{:<30}==>{:<30}".format(k,v) for k, v in n.items()))
```

But it’s not helping

Comment: Turn off "smart quotes" when posting code.

Comment: try, ``print('\n'.join('{:<30}{:<30}'.format(k,v) for k, v in n.items()))``

Comment: Well, you still have text `==>` in your second attempt. Perhaps replace that with spaces?

Comment: I tried that setting width but it’s setting the width as per the item’s width @sushant

Comment: try with `print("\n".join(f"{k:^10}==> {v:^10}" for k, v in n.items()))`, this will also align center the text

Comment: Oh yeah I have just added ==> just to display but spaces will not give me the table formatting :(

Comment: @franco I guess it won’t be specific to width of the items. For example 1 item of the dictionary has more length than the second so it will set 10 width to each individual items

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `pandas` solution:

```
import pandas as pd 
n = {'abcd':'alpha','efg':'beta'}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(n, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns=['Key','Value']
print(df.to_csv(index=None, sep='\t'))
```

Output:

```
Key     Value
abcd    alpha
efg     beta
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple string:

```
n = {"abcd": "alpha", "efg": "beta"}

s = "Key\tValue\n" + "\n".join("{}\t{}".format(*i) for i in n.items())
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
Key     Value
abcd    alpha
efg     beta
```